# Select range cells with blank rows

Tags: excel, vba

I've been having difficulties with figuring out how to code this select range macro to include blank rows. The worksheet is a chart with variable number of columns and rows. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("A5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

The selection step in the macro will only go so far as that blank row and won't go any further (obviously because it's blank hehe). For that reason, I tried adapting this discontiguous type of code but with no luck:

```
Sub SelectRangeDown_Discontiguous()
    Range("A5", Range("A65536").End(xlUp)).Select
End Sub
```

I was hoping someone could help me figure out the best way of writing this code? Am I on the right path?

Comment: Try `Range(Range("A5"),Cells(Rows.Count,3).End(xlUp)).Select`. You need the `Range` wrap around the `A5` in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @Scott.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `.End(xlToRight)` or `.End(xlDown)` you are going to stop at blank cells. If you are using `Range("A65536").End(xlUp)` then you are only selecting a single column but you are getting everything from A5 down to the last populated cell and bypassing interim blank cells. Extend this latter method laterally.

```
Sub Macro1()
    with Range("A5")
        .resize(cells(rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row - (.row - 1), _
                cells(5, columns.count).end(xltoleft).column - (.column - 1)).Copy
    end with
End Sub
```

This would be better with a [.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980(v=office.11).aspx) [Worksheet Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx).

You do not need to [.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197597.aspx) method something in order to [.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx) it¹.

---

¹ <sub>See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much @Jeeped. This worked perfectly. I appreciate your detailed explanation about extending the selection across all columns.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub whatever()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set r1 = Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count))
    Set r2 = Intersect(r1, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Gary's Student. I appreciate your detailed breakdown aspect of your code. Very logical.